# Merging array keys into "key intervals"

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array which represents a schedule:

```
Array (
    [1] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [2] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [3] => 10:00 &mdash; 00:00
    [4] => 10:00 &mdash; 00:00
    [6] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [7] => 10:00 &mdash; 18:00, 20:00 &mdash; 00:00
)
```

keys are day numbers, values are formatted time intervals. What I would like to get is a new array where days will be grouped into intervals like so:

```
Array (
    [1 &mdash; 2] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [3 &mdash; 4] => 10:00 &mdash; 00:00
    [6] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [7] => 10:00 &mdash; 18:00, 20:00 &mdash; 00:00
)
```

It is essential if, for example, I will have 3 or more days with the same time interval they will be grouped like so: `[FIRST_DAY &mdash; LAST_DAY] => ...`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate over each key/value in your input array (eg `$myArray`), and keep a note of the previous value.  When the value changes, append an entry to an output `$result` array.

Setup:

```
$myArray = [
    1 => '10:00 &mdash; 22:00',
    2 => '10:00 &mdash; 22:00',
    3 => '10:00 &mdash; 00:00',
    4 => '10:00 &mdash; 00:00',
    6 => '10:00 &mdash; 22:00',
    7 => '10:00 &mdash; 18:00, 20:00 &mdash; 00:00',
];

$result = [];
$previousValueString = null;
$startDayNumber = null;
```

Main loop:

```
foreach ($myArray as $dayNumber => $valueString) {
    if ($startDayNumber === null) {
        $startDayNumber = $dayNumber;
    } else {
        if ($valueString != $previousValueString) {
            $dayRange = $startDayNumber;
            if ($startDayNumber != $previousDayNumber) {
                $dayRange .= ' &mdash; ' . $previousDayNumber;
            }
            $result[$dayRange] = $previousValueString;
            $startDayNumber = $dayNumber;
        }
    }

    $previousDayNumber = $dayNumber;
    $previousValueString = $valueString;
}
```

You have to deal with the end case specially:

```
$dayRange = $startDayNumber;
if ($startDayNumber != $previousDayNumber) {
    $dayRange .= ' &mdash; ' . $previousDayNumber;
}
$result[$dayRange] = $valueString;
```

If you then do `print_r($result);` you get this:

```
Array
(
    [1 &mdash; 2] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [3 &mdash; 4] => 10:00 &mdash; 00:00
    [6] => 10:00 &mdash; 22:00
    [7] => 10:00 &mdash; 18:00, 20:00 &mdash; 00:00
)
```